# mv: Move file only if destination does not exist

Tags: shell, files, mv

Can I use `mv file1 file2` in a way that it only moves `file1` to `file2` if `file2` doesn't exist?

I've tried

```
yes n | mv -i file1 file2
```

(this lets `mv` ask if file2 should be overridden and automatically answer no) but besides abusing `-i` it also doesn't give me nice error codes (always 141 instead of 0 if moved and something else if not moved)

Comment: You must have the `pipefail` option on as 141 would be the exit status of `yes`, not `mv` which would have no reason to get a SIGPIPE here.

Comment: That approach also fails if file2 is a directory (it will move file1 into the file2 directory). GNU mv has a `-T` for that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If the desire is to use the exit status of `mv` rather than that of `yes`, the simplest solution might be `mv -i file1 file2 < <(yes n)`

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`mv -vn file1 file2`. This command will do what you want. You can skip `-v` if you want.

`-v` makes it verbose - mv will tell you that it moved file if it moves it(useful, since there is possibility that file will not be moved)

`-n` moves only if file2 does not exist.

Please note however, that [this is not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) as [mentioned by ThomasDickey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248544/mv-move-file-only-if-destination-does-not-exist/248547?noredirect=1#comment427679_248547).

Comment: I thought this question was trivial. Looked at the man page but didn't find it. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Fabian Happens all the time. Happy to help!

Comment: However, it's not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html).

Comment: @ThomasDickey does POSIX support this in an atomic way at all?

Comment: Added this information to the answer.

Comment: to @Fabian: Probably not, but even within the suggested answers there's the possibility of a race within the tools, depending how they are written.

Comment: if file2 exists but is a directory or symlink to directory, file1 will be moved into that directory. GNU mv has a -T option to prevent that.

Comment: Note that with both GNU mv and FreeBSD mv (the only implementations that support -n AFAIK), the exit status whether the file has been successfully renamed or not renamed because the target existed.

Comment: this seems not to be race free, `strace` shows that it uses (on my system): stat("file2", 0x7ffe3e705d10)           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("file1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("file2", 0x7ffe3e705a10)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rename("file1", "file2")                = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek). So rename seems to be used. 
@StéphaneChazelas solution seems to be the right one if you really want to do it race free.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't use `renameat2`

Answer (score 19):

`mv -n`

From `man mv` on a GNU system:

> -n, --no-clobber
>       do not overwrite an existing file

On a FreeBSD system:

> `-n` Do not overwrite an existing file.  (The -n option overrides any
>           previous -f or -i options.)

Comment: "mv -n" doesn't work well in older GNU versions, see this alternative https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/700166/43233

Answer (score 11):

```
if [ ! -e file2 ] && [ ! -L file2 ]
then
    mv file1 file2
# else echo >&2 there is already a file2 file.
fi
```

Or:

```
if ! ls -d file2 > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    mv file1 file2
fi
```

Would only run `mv` if `file2` doesn't exist. Note that it does not guarantee that a `file2` won't be overridden because a `file2` could have been created between the test and the `mv`, but note that at least current versions of GNU `mv` with `-i` or `-n` don't give that guarantee either (though the race condition is narrower there since the check is done within `mv`).

On the other end, it is portable, allows you to discriminate between the cases, and works regardless of the type of the `file2` file (regular, pipe, even *directory*).

Comment: does this introduce a race condition where a file could be written between the existence check and the move?

Comment: Always a possibility whatever you do.

Comment: Linux API has `renameat2` which you can give a `RENAME_NOREPLACE` flag. I believe this atomically checks file existence and then moves the file.

Comment: -d for directories, or -l for links, or even -e for any file type

Comment: the rename may be race free but the rest of the mv command isn't. If it thinks it doesn't need to unlink then suddenly the rename fails it would (should) error.

Comment: All this whingeing is irrelevant since we don't know the situation or what these files are. You're bringing up situations that are most likely not going to exist except in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: That looks a good expansion on the answer to me.

Answer (score 9):

A race-free approach with GNU `ln` provided `file1` is not of type *directory*:

```
ln -PT file1 file2 && rm file1
```

(Except for bugs in some network file systems), that guarantees that no `file2` file will get overridden (or that if `file2` is of type directory, `file1` will not be moved into it), because the `link()` system call, contrary to the `rename()` system call will fail if the target exists.

However, there will be an intermediate state where the file exists both as `file1` and `file2`.

The `-T` option (to always do a `link("file1", "file2")` even if `file2` is of type directory) is GNU-specific.

You could also use the `link` command:

```
link file1 file2 && rm file1
```

However, if `file1` is a symlink, depending on the implementation, `file2` will be either a hardlink to that symlink or to the target of that symlink (on Solaris, use `/usr/sbin/link`, not `/usr/xpg4/bin/link`).

Comment: do you know if the linux api `renameat2` with flag `RENAME_NOREPLACE` is atomic?

Comment: @Fabian, AFAICT it's meant to but it's very new and not supported for all filesystems. Going forward, we can expect future mv implementations on Linux to use that. That's what it was designed for.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `test -e name` which will return true if the name exists (regardless of file, directory or symlink).

For example:

```
touch file
mkdir dir
ln -s file symlink
test -e file && echo file exists
test -e dir && echo dir exists
test -e symlink && echo symlink exists
test -e file || echo you wont see this echo
test -e doesnotexist || echo doesnotexist does not exist...
```

Comment: But `ln -s doesnotexist exists; test -e exists || echo "does it really not exist?"`. Same with for instance `ln -s /var/spool/cron/crontabs/. exists` (and you're not root or member of the crontab group).

Answer (score 2):

To move only if destination doesn't exist, but **also if source exists**:

```
[[ ! -e src ]] || [[ -e dest ]] || mv src dest
```

Using `!` NOT `||` OR is safer when running bash script with `set -e`, since it will not break the script with a non-zero exit code, like `[[ false ]] && ...` can.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that `mv` might not have the non-standard `-n` (or `--no-clobber`) option, as is the case on e.g. OpenBSD, NetBSD, and AIX.

Using `mv -i` will trigger an interaction if the destination file exists.  This allows the user to avoid overwriting the destination by answering affirmatively.

If the user does *not* answer at all, `mv` will not overwrite the destination and will exit with a zero exit status:

```bsh
mv -i file1 file2 </dev/null
```

The fact that the pipeline shown in the question exits with a non-zero exit status indicates that the `pipefail` shell option is set in the `bash` shell.

The command in this answer would exit with a zero exit status in the same scenario, regardless of the state of the `pipefail` shell option. It would not exit with a non-zero status since no error was encountered.

To determine whether the file was renamed or not, a simple extra test could be added:

```bsh
mv -i file1 file2 </dev/null && [ ! -e file1 ]
```

This would exit with a non-zero exit status if the file was not renamed, or if `mv` failed for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

`mv -n` (no-clobber) might not work properly in older GNU versions:

```
$ mv --version
mv (GNU coreutils) 8.22

$ pwd
/home/user

$ mv -n ./myfile /home/user/myfile
mv: './myfile' and '/home/user/myfile' are the same file

$ echo $?
1
```

To workaround this, check if FILE1 and FILE2 have the same device and inode numbers with `-ef`, before moving the file:

```
$ [[ ./myfile -ef /home/user/myfile ]] || mv ./myfile /home/user/myfile

$ echo $?
0
```